# how do i display the coordinates of a random triangle in actionscript 2.0?

Tags: flash, geometry, coordinates, actionscript-2

I wanna generate a random triangle with coordinates, which shows the arcs of each corner in actionscript 2.0 with flash 8.0.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i display the coordinates of a random triangle in a graph which ranges from +10 to -10 XY axis in actionscript 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572271/how-do-i-display-the-coordinates-of-a-random-triangle-in-a-graph-which-ranges-fr)

Answer (score 2):

This looks a lot like your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552824/how-to-draw-a-triangle-in-a-math-graph) (also a lot like [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546579/actionscript2-0-drawing-arc-for-triangles-angle)), but here goes:

```
import flash.geom.Point;

function randomPoint():Point {  //return a random point on the stage
    var p:Point = new Point(Math.floor(Math.random()*(Stage.width-300)), Math.floor(Math.random()*Stage.height));
    return p;
}

function drawTriangle(mc:MovieClip, q1:Point, q2:Point, q3:Point):Void {//draws a triangle through 3 points
    var stroke=2;//line weight of triangle
    mc.lineStyle(stroke, 0x000000, 100, true, "none", "round", "round");
    mc.moveTo(q1.x, q1.y);
    mc.lineTo(q2.x, q2.y);
    mc.lineTo(q3.x, q3.y);
    mc.lineTo(q1.x, q1.y);
}

function drawCircle(target_mc:MovieClip, x:Number, y:Number):Void {
    //draws a red circle, centred on (x,y)
    var radius:Number=18;
    var k1:Number=Math.tan(Math.PI / 8) * radius;
    var k2:Number=Math.sin(Math.PI / 4) * radius;
    with (target_mc) {
        lineStyle(2, 0xFF0000, 100, true, "none", "round", "round");
        moveTo(x + radius, y);
        curveTo(radius + x, k1 + y, k2 + x, k2 + y);
        curveTo(k1 + x, radius + y, x, radius + y);
        curveTo(-k1 + x, radius+ y, -k2 + x, k2 + y);
        curveTo(-radius + x, k1 + y, -radius + x, y);
        curveTo(-radius + x, -k1 + y, -k2 + x, -k2 + y);
        curveTo(-k1 + x, -radius + y, x, -radius + y);
        curveTo(k1 + x, -radius + y, k2 + x, -k2 + y);
        curveTo(radius + x, -k1 + y, radius + x, y);
        }
}

function arcTriangle():MovieClip {  //main function to draw a triangle with corner arcs
    //make a new movieclip t which will hold our triangle parts
    var depth=this.getNextHighestDepth();
    var t:MovieClip = this.createEmptyMovieClip("t"+depth, depth);

    //define 3 random points (stored as properties of t)
    t.p1=randomPoint();
    t.p2=randomPoint();
    t.p3=randomPoint();

    //draw a triangle
    t.createEmptyMovieClip("triangle", 0);
    drawTriangle(t.triangle, t.p1, t.p2, t.p3);

    //draw a filled triangle to use as a mask
    t.createEmptyMovieClip("mask", 1);
    t.mask.beginFill(0xF0F0F0);
    drawTriangle(t.mask, t.p1, t.p2, t.p3);
    t.mask.endFill();
    t.mask._alpha=0;

    //add a red circle to each corner
    t.createEmptyMovieClip("arcHolder", 2);
    drawCircle(t.arcHolder,t.p1.x,t.p1.y);
    drawCircle(t.arcHolder,t.p2.x,t.p2.y);
    drawCircle(t.arcHolder,t.p3.x,t.p3.y);

    //mask the circles so only the interior arcs are visible
    t.arcHolder.setMask(t.mask);

    //show the coordinates (from bottom-left corner of the stage) for each point
    t.createTextField("text1",3,t.p1.x,t.p1.y,300,100);
    t.text1.text="("+t.p1.x+", "+(Stage.height-t.p1.y)+")";
    t.createTextField("text2",4,t.p2.x,t.p2.y,300,100);
    t.text2.text="("+t.p2.x+", "+(Stage.height-t.p2.y)+")";
    t.createTextField("text3",5,t.p3.x,t.p3.y,300,100);
    t.text3.text="("+t.p3.x+", "+(Stage.height-t.p3.y)+")";

    return t;
}

var myTriangle:MovieClip = arcTriangle();
```

It should look a bit like this when you're done:

[image]
<sub>(source: [webfactional.com](http://roi.webfactional.com/img/so/triangle2.jpg))</sub>

If either (or both) of my answers are helpful to you, please **accept** them by clicking the big tick-mark ([image: tick]
) on the left-hand side. Thank you.